# How would I go about home networking?

Tags: networking, home-networking

I'd like to build a home network, but I have absolutely no clue where to start.

My home has 6-7 computers, some personal and two are shared.

I'd like to have network based accounts that can log in on any of the computers, if you know what I mean? They all run Windows.

I'd also like to have a network printer, and I'd like all of the computers to back themselves up to my NAS/Server.

Could anyone point me in the correct direction of how to do this?

Also, what OS should I use on this server/NAS. I'd like to have a samba share of some sort on it, to save & share random files throughout my network. I'm assuming I should go Linux based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily done using, say, Ubuntu server with Samba installed and configured. Configure it as a domain controller and then all your computers can log in using the accounts you create on the server. It's a bit of configuration but I've done it for a number of small businesses and works quite well - until you start to rely on things like Group Policy. Samba cannot do GP very nicely. Also,  you need to configure your clients' DNS addresses manually to point to Ubuntu.

There are a number of good resources on the net. Good luck!

On an additional note,  if you've got a spare 64-Bit machine with a fairly decent spec, for about £300 you could buy Windows Server 2012 Essentials. Then you can run a proper Windows domain that is easily configured and Group Policy. Overkill, definitely. But easily configured and your devices connect straight away.

Comment: Is there a specific thing that this process is called that would make the search a bit easier, or should I search for ubuntu domain controller, etc?

Comment: Ubuntu domain controller, yes :)

Comment: Okay, cool. I can obtain a copy of Windows Server 2012 Essentials from a friend of mine who runs SolidShellSecurity. The machine I'll be running this on has 8GB RAM and a 3.0GHz Quad Core processor. Good enough for it?

Comment: Just so long as it's 64-Bit it'll work. You should add am additional ethernet card into it too. It's important, if you use Windows Server as PDC, that it is the DHCP server for your network. You can keep your router dishing out DHCP to the "wan" adapter of your new server2012 but make sure the ip range and subnet aren't the same. The server2012 dhcp server is then bound to the LAN adapter and services your internal computers and printets.

Comment: Alright, sounds good. I think I'm gonna go with Ubuntu, it just seems simpler and I like a Linux environment much better. Especially when I can disable the GUI to free up resources. Thanks for your help, man!

Comment: Just download the Ubuntu server edition ;) no GUI! Go hard or go home!

Comment: Exactly! CLI works too aha.